# Keep single radio button unchecked on page load

Tags: javascript, html

I have a radio button in my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="radio" name="r"/>
</body>
</html>
```

If I check it, and reload the page (Firefox 20.0.1) it will stay checked. But if I clear the cache (ctrl+f5) the button gets unchecked again.

Is there any way to make it consistent so that it always unchecks itself when the page is refreshed? Or do I need to involve javascript? I've tried with and without the `name` property.

PS. I wasn't able to make a fiddle. Try it on a local file in order to reproduce it.

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to do this crossbrowser without JS...I may be wrong tho.

Comment: @elclanrs I was afraid that this comes down to individual browser behaviour...

Comment: I think, you have to use javascript for this. clearing cache is a bad practice, as most of the sites depend on it.

Comment: [Here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/2fAuY/show/) is a fiddle that reproduced the problem in my Firefox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set `autocomplete="off"`:

```
<input type="radio" name="r" autocomplete="off" />
```

Please check this documentations:

[Mozilla Dev](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion)

[W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp)

And working example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/2fAuY/2/show/ (thank you @ValarDohaeris for fiddle)

Comment: Yes it should. On W3S documentation there is information about supporting all major browsers.